# Inset shadow on non-square-objects in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, shadow

I'm trying to create a webpage with some tabs and I want the tabs that are not selected to "lie behind" the active tab. I've got different tabs with different appearances, one is plain square but the other is a trapezoid.

I've managed to create the shadow effect on the square tab by using

```
"-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #555;"
```

but that doesn't work for the trapezoid.

This is a simplified example of my code:

HTML

```
<div id="first-tab">
</div>
<div id="second-tab">
</div>
<div id="main-content">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#first-tab {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ED3627;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #555;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
}

#second-tab {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-bottom: 70px solid #365F91;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 60px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #555; /* Doesn't work */
}

#main-content {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #365F91;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nx9ex/

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix this?

It only has to work for Chrome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but can be a start:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Nx9ex/3/)

It didn't work because the second tab had really a height of 0px, and was in top of the trapezoid, the visible portion being the border.

I changed the method of creating a trapezoid, now it has all the space and the corner is hide setting there a transparent background:

```
#second-tab {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(-114deg, transparent 30px, #365F91 31px);
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #555; /* Doesn't work */
}
```

The remaing problem is that the shadow is slightly visible in the transparent border

Comment: Wow, didn't see this reply until now! Thanks for answering but I tried this method too and as you say you can see the shadow to the right...

I ended up putting a shadow on the big box instead and changing the z-index of the tabs when you clicked them :)